# GPG: notify before password prompt in terminal

Tags: linux, gnupg, gpg-agent

I use GPG to encrypt a file in a shell script (in Linux). The file to be encrypted is created for a long time, so the script is executed in background, and I don't see when the password prompt is appeared (the prompt is textual, not GUI). If I not enter the password in a timeout, the operation is failed.

The file encryption takes long time also, so I can't just put a notification command before calling GPG.

So I want GPG notify me about right before the password prompt. For example, with a bell (\07) or a custom command. How to do that?

Comment: You could perhaps [Suppress the passphrase prompt in GPG command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072403/suppress-the-passphrase-prompt-in-gpg-command).

Comment: @harrymc: I don't want to write password in the shell script or using an asymmetric encryption.

Comment: Why not do the encrypting in a separate console in the foreground, so you can answer the prompt?

Answer (score 0):

I assume "the script is executed in background" means you pay attention to other things. Not "in background" like `thescript &`.

<sup>Executing the script *really* in the background would make it unable to read from the terminal (until you `fg` it); so if this is what you do then start executing the script in the foreground, in a separate terminal if needed (`tmux` is great for this).</sup>

Use the following script to catch possible password prompts in the output of an arbitrary command:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set command [lindex $argv 0]
spawn -noecho {*}"$argv"
interact -o -re "(^|\[^\n\]+)\\m\[Pp\]\[Aa\]\[Ss\]\[Ss\](\[Ww\]\[Oo\]\[Rr\]\[Dd\]|\[Pp\]\[Hh\]\[Rr\]\[Aa\]\[Ss\]\[Ee\]).*" {
   set match "$interact_out(0,string)"
   send_user "$match"
   send_tty "\a"
   spawn -noecho notify-send "Possible password prompt from `$command'" "$match"
   wait
}
```

Save it (e.g.) as `catch-pass-prompt` and make it executable (`chmod +x catch-pass-prompt`). Example usage:

```
./catch-pass-prompt sh -c '
sleep 2
echo line with Passphrase to stdout, bell expected
sleep 2
echo dummy line, no bell expected
sleep 2
echo line with PASSWORD to stderr, bell expected >&2
sleep 2
echo line with compass, no bell expected
sleep 2
echo line with PaSSword1 to tty, bell expected >/dev/tty
'
```

You will use it like `./catch-pass-prompt gpg …`.

`send_tty "\a"` is responsible for printing a bell character to the terminal.

`spawn -noecho notify-send …` is an example of how to run a custom command (here `notify-send …`). You may want to omit or change it (especially if you don't use `notify-send`).

Notes:

- I don't know `gpg`, I don't know if `password` or `passphrase` is the right pattern to look for. Adjust the code to your needs.
- I'm not very proud of the regex I created. It's awful because `-nocase` seems not to work for me; and `\\m` also does not work as I expected; I'm not going to investigate further.
- Other parts of the script may also be sub-optimal. My experience with `expect` is limited. Treat the script as a proof of concept.
- Like the example shows, the script will capture and analyze what the given command prints to its stdout, stderr and tty (provided by `expect`). `expect` will merge these and print to its stdout. This means you won't be able to tell stdout and stderr of the requested command apart, e.g. you won't be able to redirect them separately.
- The example code doesn't ask for password. I have tested with `ssh` that actually does ask.
- Your terminal emulator may ignore bell characters; or it may react to them in any way. It's your job to configure your terminal emulator, so the bell does not go unnoticed.
- My testbed: Kubuntu 22.04 LTS, `expect` version 5.45.4.